# cant add array number in dynamic cakephp form

Tags: php, jquery, forms, cakephp, dynamic

I am trying to make a dynamic form in CakePHP, but it seems not to work.

What can I do to make it work; I can't get `data[AppliedCourses][0][institution]`, can't get `data[AppliedCourses][1][institution]`, `data[AppliedCourses][2][institution]`, etc.

```
<table id="mytable2" style="border: 0px;">
<tbody>
    <tr id="InstitutionApplied0">
        <td>
            <button type="button" title="Click Here to remove Institution Applied" style="display: none;">-</button>
            <div class="input text">
                <label for="AppliedCourses0Institution">Institution Name</label>
                <input name="data[AppliedCourses][0][institution]" type="text" id="AppliedCourses0Institution" />
            </div>
            <div class="input select">
                <label for="AppliedCourses0CourseId">Course Of Interest</label>
                <select name="data[AppliedCourses][0][course_id]" id="AppliedCourses0CourseId">
                    <option value="1">Applied Sciences</option>
                    <option value="2">Architecture & Built Enviroment</option>
                    <option value="3">Art & Design</option>
                    <option value="4">Business / Commerce</option>
                    <option value="5">Computing & IT</option>
                    <option value="6">Communication & Media Studies</option>
                    <option value="7">Education & Language</option>
                    <option value="8">Engineering</option>
                    <option value="9">Environmental Science</option>
                    <option value="10">Health Sciences</option>
                    <option value="11">Hospitality & Tourism</option>
                    <option value="12">Humanities & Social Sciences</option>
                    <option value="13">Law & Legal Studies</option>
                    <option value="14">Music</option>
                    <option value="15">Others</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="input text">
                <label for="AppliedCourse0Major">Major Field Of Course</label>
                <input name="data[AppliedCourse][0][major]" maxlength="255" type="text" id="AppliedCourse0Major" />
            </div>
            <div class="input date">
                <label for="AppliedCourses0IntakeMonth">Intake</label>
                <select name="data[AppliedCourses][0][intake][month]" id="AppliedCourses0IntakeMonth">
                    <option value="01">January</option>
                    <option value="02">February</option>
                    <option value="03" selected="selected">March</option>
                    <option value="04">April</option>
                    <option value="05">May</option>
                    <option value="06">June</option>
                    <option value="07">July</option>
                    <option value="08">August</option>
                    <option value="09">September</option>
                    <option value="10">October</option>
                    <option value="11">November</option>
                    <option value="12">December</option>
                </select>-
                <select name="data[AppliedCourses][0][intake][year]" id="AppliedCourses0IntakeYear">
                    <option value="2035">2035</option>
                    <option value="2034">2034</option>
                    <option value="2033">2033</option>
                    <option value="2032">2032</option>
                    <option value="2031">2031</option>
                    <option value="2030">2030</option>
                    <option value="2029">2029</option>
                    <option value="2028">2028</option>
                    <option value="2027">2027</option>
                    <option value="2026">2026</option>
                    <option value="2025">2025</option>
                    <option value="2024">2024</option>
                    <option value="2023">2023</option>
                    <option value="2022">2022</option>
                    <option value="2021">2021</option>
                    <option value="2020">2020</option>
                    <option value="2019">2019</option>
                    <option value="2018">2018</option>
                    <option value="2017">2017</option>
                    <option value="2016">2016</option>
                    <option value="2015" selected="selected">2015</option>
                    <option value="2014">2014</option>
                    <option value="2013">2013</option>
                    <option value="2012">2012</option>
                    <option value="2011">2011</option>
                    <option value="2010">2010</option>
                    <option value="2009">2009</option>
                    <option value="2008">2008</option>
                    <option value="2007">2007</option>
                    <option value="2006">2006</option>
                    <option value="2005">2005</option>
                    <option value="2004">2004</option>
                    <option value="2003">2003</option>
                    <option value="2002">2002</option>
                    <option value="2001">2001</option>
                    <option value="2000">2000</option>
                    <option value="1999">1999</option>
                    <option value="1998">1998</option>
                    <option value="1997">1997</option>
                    <option value="1996">1996</option>
                    <option value="1995">1995</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="input date">
                <label for="AppliedCourses0SubmissionDateDay">Submission Date</label>
                <select name="data[AppliedCourses][0][submission_date][day]" id="AppliedCourses0SubmissionDateDay">
                    <option value="01">1</option>
                    <option value="02" selected="selected">2</option>
                    <option value="03">3</option>
                    <option value="04">4</option>
                    <option value="05">5</option>
                    <option value="06">6</option>
                    <option value="07">7</option>
                    <option value="08">8</option>
                    <option value="09">9</option>
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                    <option value="11">11</option>
                    <option value="12">12</option>
                    <option value="13">13</option>
                    <option value="14">14</option>
                    <option value="15">15</option>
                    <option value="16">16</option>
                    <option value="17">17</option>
                    <option value="18">18</option>
                    <option value="19">19</option>
                    <option value="20">20</option>
                    <option value="21">21</option>
                    <option value="22">22</option>
                    <option value="23">23</option>
                    <option value="24">24</option>
                    <option value="25">25</option>
                    <option value="26">26</option>
                    <option value="27">27</option>
                    <option value="28">28</option>
                    <option value="29">29</option>
                    <option value="30">30</option>
                    <option value="31">31</option>
                </select>-
                <select name="data[AppliedCourses][0][submission_date][month]" id="AppliedCourses0SubmissionDateMonth">
                    <option value="01">January</option>
                    <option value="02">February</option>
                    <option value="03" selected="selected">March</option>
                    <option value="04">April</option>
                    <option value="05">May</option>
                    <option value="06">June</option>
                    <option value="07">July</option>
                    <option value="08">August</option>
                    <option value="09">September</option>
                    <option value="10">October</option>
                    <option value="11">November</option>
                    <option value="12">December</option>
                </select>-
                <select name="data[AppliedCourses][0][submission_date][year]" id="AppliedCourses0SubmissionDateYear">
                    <option value="2035">2035</option>
                    <option value="2034">2034</option>
                    <option value="2033">2033</option>
                    <option value="2032">2032</option>
                    <option value="2031">2031</option>
                    <option value="2030">2030</option>
                    <option value="2029">2029</option>
                    <option value="2028">2028</option>
                    <option value="2027">2027</option>
                    <option value="2026">2026</option>
                    <option value="2025">2025</option>
                    <option value="2024">2024</option>
                    <option value="2023">2023</option>
                    <option value="2022">2022</option>
                    <option value="2021">2021</option>
                    <option value="2020">2020</option>
                    <option value="2019">2019</option>
                    <option value="2018">2018</option>
                    <option value="2017">2017</option>
                    <option value="2016">2016</option>
                    <option value="2015" selected="selected">2015</option>
                    <option value="2014">2014</option>
                    <option value="2013">2013</option>
                    <option value="2012">2012</option>
                    <option value="2011">2011</option>
                    <option value="2010">2010</option>
                    <option value="2009">2009</option>
                    <option value="2008">2008</option>
                    <option value="2007">2007</option>
                    <option value="2006">2006</option>
                    <option value="2005">2005</option>
                    <option value="2004">2004</option>
                    <option value="2003">2003</option>
                    <option value="2002">2002</option>
                    <option value="2001">2001</option>
                    <option value="2000">2000</option>
                    <option value="1999">1999</option>
                    <option value="1998">1998</option>
                    <option value="1997">1997</option>
                    <option value="1996">1996</option>
                    <option value="1995">1995</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <button type="button" title="Click Here to add another Institution" onclick="addInstitution()">+</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

and the JS

```
<script>
var lastRowInstitutionApplied = 0;

function addInstitution() {
    lastRowInstitutionApplied++;
    $("#mytable2 tbody>tr:#InstitutionApplied0").clone(true).attr('id', 'InstitutionApplied' + lastRowInstitutionApplied).removeAttr('style').insertBefore("#mytable2 tbody>tr:#trAdd3");
    $("#InstitutionApplied" + lastRowInstitutionApplied + " button").attr('onclick', 'removeInstitutionApplied(' + lastRowInstitutionApplied + ')').attr('style', 'display:block;');
    $("#InstitutionApplied" + lastRowInstitutionApplied + " input:first").attr('name', 'data[appliedCourse][' + lastRowInstitutionApplied + '][institution]').attr('id', 'AppliedCourseInstitution' + lastRowInstitutionApplied);
    $("#InstitutionApplied0" + lastRowInstitutionApplied + " select").attr('name', 'data[appliedCourse][' + lastRowInstitutionApplied + '][course_id]').attr('id', 'AppliedCourseCourseId' + lastRowInstitutionApplied);
    $("#InstitutionApplied0" + lastRowInstitutionApplied + " input:eq(2)").attr('name', 'data[appliedCourse][' + lastRowInstitutionApplied + '][major]').attr('id', 'AppliedCourseCourseMajor' + lastRowInstitutionApplied);
    $("#InstitutionApplied" + lastRowInstitutionApplied + " select(1)").attr('name', 'data[AppliedCourse][' + lastRowInstitutionApplied + '][intake]').attr('id', 'AppliedCourseIntake' + lastRowInstitutionApplied);
    $("#InstitutionApplied" + lastRowInstitutionApplied + " select(2)").attr('name', 'data[AppliedCourse][' + lastRowInstitutionApplied + '][submission_date]').attr('id', 'AppliedCourseDate' + lastRowInstitutionApplied);

}

function removeInstitutionApplied(x) {
    $("#InstitutionApplied" + x).remove();
    lastRowInstitutionApplied--;
}

</script>
```

Comment: What does this have to do with CakePHP?  It's building a javascript form, right?

Comment: Have you debugged enough to see whether lastRowInstitutionApplied is actually getting incremented each time you call the function?  If so, how far does it make it in your JS code?  Are there error(s)?

Comment: well thats the issue the form is generated by cakephp  and now the date and select is not getting the increment only the name is ok.